# change the background color of the dates in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I have `implemented a jquery fullcalendar` in a ROR application. In the month view of fullcalendar, `I need to change the background color of the dates from start date to end date.` I got the start date and end date. But I am not able to `change the background color of these dates`. I have tried like below but it is changing for all the months(from start date to end date) of the calendar. Is there any other way to achieve this?? Please help. I am a novice in Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var calInstance = $('#calendar')
$('.task_name').live('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pending_task_details',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            task_id: this.id
        },
        success: function (data, response, event, date) {
            var start_date = new Date(data.start_date);
            var end_date = new Date(data.end_date);
            alert("The start date is....." + start_date);
            alert("The end date is..........." + end_date);
            for (i = start_date; i <= end_date; i = new Date(i.getTime() + 86400000)) {
                getCellFromDate(i, calInstance);
            }
        }
    });
});


function getCellFromDate(thisDate, calInstance) {
    var d = thisDate.getDate();
    var m = thisDate.getMonth();
    var y = thisDate.getFullYear();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', y, m, d);
    var coords = calInstance.fullCalendar('getView').dateCell(new Date(thisDate)),
        $row = calInstance.find('.fc-view-month tbody tr').eq(coords.row),
        $cell = $row.find('td').eq(coords.col);
    $($cell).find('.fc-day-number').parent().css('background-color', '#6E5849');
    $($cell).find('.fc-day-number').css({
        'background-color': '#6E5849',
        'border': '1px solid #6E5849'
    })
}
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hello Jai. Please find the link of fiddle for the above.http://jsfiddle.net/mA5AT/2/

Comment: Here it is changing the background color of the cells. But since it is taking the coords of the cells, It is changing for all the months on the same coordinates

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is "select" the days in the calendar, right - by changing the background of start-date to end-date? If so, have you checked the `select` method? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/

Comment: I dont want to select the dates. I am getting the start date and end date from the rails controller.. I just need to change the background color of those dates in the jquery fullcalendar. Please check this jsfiddle.. jsfiddle.net/mA5AT/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a function get a handle on the day of the month element

Something like this:

```js
     // based on the given event date return the full calendar day jquery object (<td ...>)
     // matching day and month
     //
     // assumptions:
     //  - the event date is if for the same year as the current viewable month
     //  - the fc-day* TD's are in chronological order
     //  - the fc-day* TD's not for the current month have a class of fc-other-month
     //
    findFullCalendarDayForClickedEvent : function( eventDate ) {

        var foundDay;

        var $theCalendar = $( '#myCalendar' );

        var currentDate = $theCalendar.fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
        var fullCalendarDayContainers = $theCalendar.find( 'td[class*="fc-day"]' );

        for( var i = 0; i < fullCalendarDayContainers.length; i++ ) {

            var $currentContainer = $( fullCalendarDayContainers[ i ] );

            var dayNumber = $currentContainer.find( '.fc-day-number' ).html();

            // first find the matching day
            if ( eventDate.getDate() == dayNumber ) {

                // now month check, if our current container has fc-other-month
                // then the event month and the current month needs to mismatch,
                // otherwise container is missing fc-other-month then the event
                // month and current month need to match
                if( $currentContainer.hasClass( 'fc-other-month' ) ) {

                    if( eventDate.getMonth() != currentDate.getMonth() ) {
                        foundDay = $currentContainer;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ( eventDate.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth() ) {
                        foundDay = $currentContainer;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return foundDay;
    }
```

For more see: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13647014/edit

Next loop over your time frame passing in each date to the finder function.

Then

```
foundDay.addClass( 'selected-day' );
```